# Why isnt my image rendering or translating as expected?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-ref

I'm trying to place an image over a background, where it is translated around the background based on the value of `this.pitchWidth`. The property of `this.playerRef` seems to update correctly inside `componentDidMount` but for some reason the image with `className="fas fa-tshirt GK"` isnt rendering. Does anyone know why this is?

```
import React from 'react'
import backgroundImage from "../images/Football_Field.png";
import '../Pitch.css'

class Team extends React.Component{ 
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.playerRef = React.createRef();
        this.pitchWidth = 500; //in em
        this.styles = {transform:''}
    }
    componentDidMount = ()=>{
        this.playerRef.current.style.transform = `translate(100em,${this.pitchWidth/2}em)`
        console.log(this.playerRef)
    }
    render(){
        let style = {
            margin:'auto',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundImage:'url('+ backgroundImage +')',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
            width: this.pitchWidth,
            height: '400px',
            border: '2px dashed #333',
            backgroundSize: '100% 100%'
        }
        return (
            <div className="pitch-container" style={style}>
                <i className="fas fa-tshirt GK" ref={this.playerRef} style={this.styles}></i>
                <i className="fas fa-tshirt LB"  ></i>
            </div>       
        )
    }
}

export default Team;
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "isn't rendering" ? Is there a node in DOM ? Are you sure it's not just outside the window ?

Comment: @Beniamin H I just cant seem to see the icon on the screen

Comment: try to find it in DOM using dev tools inspector

Comment: the console.log inside componentDidMount shows the dom element correctly which is why I'm confused

Comment: one thing (though, it's probably not the problem) you don't specify a *unit* for style width

Comment: 100em may mean that your element will be outside the window - try to change it to 1em for check